# Implementing an interface with a Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, interface

I'm new to using interfaces so I have a question that will probably be pretty easy for most of you.

I am currently trying to make an interface for a windows form. It looks something like

```
interface myInterface
{
    //stuff stuff stuff
}

public partial class myClass : Form, myInterface
{
   //More stuff stuff stuff. This is the form
}
```

The problem comes when I try to implement it. If I implement with

```
myInterface blah = new myClass();
blah.ShowDialog();
```

the ShowDialog() function is now available to it. It makes sense- myInterface is an interface, not a form... but I'm curious how I should go about implementing the interface with a windows form, or if it is even a viable option at all.

Does anyone have any suggestions about how I should go about doing that?

Thanks!

Comment: I dont understand what you want to do.. please clarify

Comment: What are you trying to do? It doesn't sound like you want an interface for whatever your doing. For example, An interface is there to share common method signatures between classes

Comment: As a side note, convention dictate that your interface should start with a capital I and be pascal-cased (ie `IMyInterface`). Objects should be pascal cased as well (`MyClass`). Take this with a grain of salt (it is, after all, a convention) but it's good to adhere to widely used practices, even coding convention.

Comment: There's just no point in declaring *blah* as the interface type.  Just declare it myClass and solve your problem.  It is only useful when you want to pass your form object to code that doesn't know anything about the *myClass* type.

Comment: @SimonBelanger `object != class` class case should be cased as you describe (I'm guessing that's what you meant). Objects don't have identity but not names

Comment: Ah, my apologies, I will explain- I am trying to create an interface to simply act as the public access for methods in my form. The form itself is a measuring tool that is pulled up to supplement other forms - it opens as a separate window (to be used on another monitor), measures something and passes the values back into the form that called it. I was hoping to use an interface to easily expose to others which methods were available for that purpose. Incorrect use of an interface, I'm guessing?

Comment: @RuneFS I think the word object in that context won't cause confusion. I used object to englobe classes and structures.

Comment: Correct (incorrect usage) - just set the accessors correctly, use `internal` for methods you want to be public only for your application

Comment: Ahhh shame, but it makes sense now. Thank you for the help! If you post that I'll use that as the answer lol

Comment: @SimonBelanger and you are entitled to that view I disagree. I spent a lot of time debating object orientation and one of the things that makes it hardest for people to get object orientation as opposed to class orientation is the confusion about what's a class and what's an object. In that view I'd say there's a lot of confuse because of our (the industry) very slopy distinction between when to use object and when to use class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a question about how to correctly expose members of a class.

```
internal - Access to a method/class is restricted to the application
public - Access is not restricted
private - Access is restricted to the current class (methods)
protected - Access is restricted to the current class and its inherited classes
```

An example use of an interface is to share common method signatures between classes

```
interface IAnimal
{
    int FeetCount();
}
public class Dog : IAnimal
{
    int FeetCount()
    {
    }
}

public class Duck : IAnimal
{
    int FeetCount()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to approach this would be to add ShowDialog to myInterface:

```
 interface myInterface
 {
     DialogResult ShowDialog();
 }
```

Now, you can call that method on the interface without having to cast.

If you want to get a little more fancy with it, you could create another interface which represents any dialog...

```
interface IDialog
{
     DialogResult ShowDialog();
}
```

Then make your other interface implement IDialog:

```
interface myInterface : IDialog
{
     //stuff stuff stuff
}
```

This has the advantage of potentially reusing more code... You can have methods which accept an argument of type IDialog and they don't have to know about myInterface.  If you implement a common base interface for all of your dialogs, you can treat the the same way:

```
void DialogHelperMethod(IDialog dialog)
{
     dialog.ShowDialog();
}

myInterface foo = new myClass();
DialogHelperMethod(foo);
```

Comment: This won't work smoothly because `ShowDialog()` is implemented in `Form` and not in `MyClass`.

Comment: @ja72 - it should work fine.  Your class inherits from Form, which implements ShowDialog

Answer (score 2):

```
interface MyInterface
{
    void Foo();
}

public partial class MyClass : Form, MyInterface
{
   //More stuff stuff stuff. This is the form
}

Form f = new MyClass();
f.ShowDialog(); // Works because MyClass implements Form
f.Foo(); // Works because MyClass implements MyInterface
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only access the items exposed by the type you use to hold myClass.  For example,

```
Form f = new MyClass();
f.ShowDialog();  // Will work because f is of type Form, which has a ShowDialog method
f.stuff(); // Works because MyClass implements myInterface which exposes stuff()
```

All the things you want are in there, but you have to reference them differently than you're trying to.

Comment: You shouldn't need to cast if a class implements a method in an interface

Comment: But in his sample code, he is using myInterface blah = new myClass(); and then trying to access members of the class, not the Interface.  My example was meant to help illustrate that if he wants to call members of Form he can't declare it the way he is.

Comment: Even if explicitly implemented cast not required `myInterface mi = f;` is enough

Comment: @Mgetz the cast is not required even if the interface is implemented explicitly. the assignment to a variable with the compile time type of said interface will do the trick

Comment: I removed the cast from this answer which does not deserve -2